# Parametrize a function with a variable. Then delete the variable

Tags: r, function, arguments

I would like to make the following code run:

```
mu = 5
rnorm2 <- function(N) rnorm(N, mean = mu, sd = 1)
```

And then be able to use the rnorm2 function regardless of the presence of the mu variable in the environment. In other words, set the value of the 'mean' argument with the "mu" value once and for all.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

**1) local with free variable** We can use `local` to capture the prior value of `mu`.

Note that the cached value of `mu` is `mu_` and is stored in the environment in which `rnorm3` is *defined* at the time it was defined as opposed to the environmnent and time when `rnorm3` is first run.

If it were desired to later set it then we could use `environment(rnorm3)$mu_ <- 5` and we can query the cached value at any time using `environment(rnorm3)$mu_` .

```
set.seed(123)
mu = 5

rnorm3 <- local({
  if (exists("mu")) mu_ <- mu
  function(N) rnorm(N, mean = mu_, sd = 1)
})

rnorm3(1)
## [1] 4.439524
rm(mu)

rnorm3(1)
## [1] 4.769823
```

**2) local using arguments** Relying on free variables, i.e. variables such as `mu` which are used but not defined in the function, may not be the best approach as it makes it harder to debug and it may be preferable to use arguments instead.  This uses the `mu` argument, if specified, and uses the value specified the last time `rnorm4` was called if not.

```
rnorm4 <- local({
  mu_ <- NA
  function(N, mu = mu_) {
     mu_ <<- mu
     rnorm(N, mu, 1)
  }
})

set.seed(123)

rnorm4(1, 5)
## [1] 4.439524

rnorm4(1)
## [1] 4.769823
```

**3) proto** Another approach is to use object oriented programming.  The proto package makes this particularly easy since it can define objects without the overhead of creating classes to instantiate them from.  We create an object `p` with a method `rnorm` (which calls `rnorm` in stats) and an attribute `mu`.  `p$rnorm` will look into `p` for `mu` so we can delete `mu` outside `p`.  Note that the the notation `p$norm(1)` says to pass the object `p` as the first argument and 1 as the second argument.  We can redefine or query `mu` at any time by setting or querying `p$mu`.

```
library(proto)
p <- proto(rnorm = function(., N) stats::rnorm(N, mu, 1))

set.seed(123)
mu <- 5

p$mu <- mu
rm(mu)
p$rnorm(1)
## [1] 4.439524
```

**4) options** Another possibility is to store `mu` as an R option.

```
set.seed(123)
options(mu = 5)

rnorm5 <- function(N, mu = getOption("mu")) rnorm(N, mu, 1)

rnorm5(1)
## [1] 4.439524
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a copy of `rnorm` and set the function defaults with `formals`:

```
mu <- 5
rnorm2 <- rnorm
formals(rnorm2)$mean <- mu
```

**Output**

```
> set.seed(1)
> rnorm2(5)
[1] 4.373546 5.183643 4.164371 6.595281 5.329508

> formals(rnorm2)
$n


$mean
[1] 5

$sd
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
rnorm2 <- function(N, mu = 5, sd = 1) rnorm(N, mean = mu, sd = sd)
```

This just sets the default mu and sd to 5 and 1 respectively.
You can deviate from the default with `rnorm2(N, 7, 2)` (or `rnorm2(N, mu = 7, sd = 2)`) which would have a mean of 7 and an sd of 2.
But if you just do `rnorm2(N)` it will have a mean of 5 and an sd of 1.
(I agree with the other answers here also, but I wonder if you were looking for a simpler answer and didn't ask the question just right.)